# IE doesn't recognize box with transparent background over an image

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/wERsY/ - where a box with a transparent background is placed half over an image in the upper left corner of the image. The image and the box are absolutely positioned and the box is given a higher z-index than the image.

With FF, Safari, and Chrome, the entire box is seen when you hover over it (cursor turns to a pointer when you're over any part of the box) and clicking the box triggers the click handler, which turns the box red.

But with IE (I'm running IE10) only the part of the box that is *not* over the image is seen. If you hover over the part of the box that is over the image, the cursor doesn't change to a pointer and clicking does nothing.

If you give the box a color background, (uncomment line 4 of the CSS) then IE sees the entire box, including the part over the image.

Does anyone understand what's going on here and how I can get a transparent box to be clickable over an image with IE?

Thanks

```
HTML
<img id='pelican' src='http://s20.postimg.org/fpitivjl9/Pelican.jpg' alt="pelican"/>
<div id='clickBox'> </div>

CSS
div#clickBox {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
/*    background-color:yellow; */
    cursor:pointer; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index=51; 
}
img#pelican {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    z-index=50; 
}

jQuery
 $('#clickBox').click(function() {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor:'red'});
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transparent` in IE is really transparent, you can't see it, mouse can't see it, if there's underlying visible element.

Use a color for background and `opacity: 0`, and change `opacity` instead of `background-color`. [A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B47xA/).

Comment: Yes, this works.  Thanks.  The only problem with it is that when you give an element a 0 opacity, _everything_ goes to 0 opacity, including the border. Just like `backgroundColor:transparent` leaves the border alone, I'd like to apply an opacity that just gives the background color 0 opacity.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't think about border, since there wasn't a border in your fiddle. How about using a `transparent` wrapper?

Comment: Yes, a wrapper around an opaque div lets me keep the wrapper border.  But the opaque div caused me all kinds of trouble because there's another layer on top of it that needs to be able to take writing and the opaque div was interfering with the contenteditable. (I know, I didn't mention this either.)  What I finally discovered is that if you put a border around the transparent box IE will see the box over an image and IE doesn't care if the border color is transparent. So the least intrusive solution is to just put a transparent border around the element.  Thanks for your input.